# CSS div (absolute) inside table th (relative), div is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am a little bit stuck here. I am tryng to create a filter pop-up for a table head. So my first thought was making the th position relative and make the div.filter position absolute. It kinda works... the 'test' part should be shown in front of the rest. But it still is inside the th tag.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
<th>
// some th stuff
    <div class="filter">
        test
    </div>
</th>
```

css:

```
th {
    position: relative;

    .filter {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

So then I thought lets add a index. But I got no result what so ever. Does anyone have a explanation what is going on here? Is there something am doing wrong or is this just not the way it works?

Comment: it's clear that there is no space for your element

Comment: Try making the z-index on the div higher than the z-index of the table.

Comment: @TemaniAfif its a absolute, so that doesnt matter right?

Comment: @Anthony I tried that as well. No result.

Comment: Have you tried making its overflow visible?

Comment: ah, yhea th overflow is hidden. So that also counts for the childeren. Damn I am stupit. Is there a way to make the childeren visible again? I already tried overflow: visible on the .filter class. Did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: visible` to your `th` selector and things should work as you expect.

Comment: Almost. Now the th text is always visible, but i want to cut that if its too long.

Comment: You cannot overflow and not-overflow a box at the same time. If you want to truncate the text inside the TH, you could try to wrap it in a <span> element with `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`.